# Скроллбар на JavaScript

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, css

Уже с неделю мучаюсь, ничего не могу понять, работа идентична во всех браузерах... ) Заранее спасибо за помощь. Написан сайт, в котором при нажатии на кнопку поиск появляеться модальное окно, в котором отображается результат поиска... Результат показан на 1 изображении.

[image: снимок сайта]

Да, но есть одно но, крестик спрятался за модальное окно, а скроллбара нету, хотя информация выходит за предел модального окна, при повторном шелчке по тем же критериям поиска ошибки испоряються... Как сделать так, чтоб ошибки исправились при первом поиске

[image: снимок сайта]

Вот код.

При нажатии на кнопку поиск: `onclick="otpravka();"`

Функция отправки:

```
function otpravka() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
        var div = document.getElementById('ModalBox');
        div.innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#ModalBox').modal();
            return false;
        })
    }
}
```

Вот Div с модальным окном:

```
<div id="ModalBox" align="center" class="none" style="z-index:3200;">
</div>
```

Вот CSS к Div:

```
#simplemodal-container {
    background-color:#333;
    border:4px solid #444;
    color:#bbb;
    height:550px;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    padding:12px;
    width:60%;
    z-index:3200;
}

#simplemodal-container #basic-modal-content {
    padding:28px;
}

#simplemodal-container a {
    color:#FF0;
}

#simplemodal-container a.modalCloseImg {
    background:url(img/x.png) no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
    height:29px;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    width:25px;
    z-index:5000;
}

#simplemodal-container p {
    color:#bbb;
}

#simplemodal-container td {
    color:#bbb;
}

#simplemodal-overlay {
    background-color:#000;
    cursor:wait;
}

#simplemodal-overlayclose {
    background-color:#FFF;
}
```

Подключаемая библиотека : jquery.simplemodal.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`overflow:auto;` - скроллы будут появляться только тогда, когда текст будет вылезать.

Comment: а теперь проблема с закрывающей модальное окно кнопочко, ее перекрывает модальное окно, игра с z-index не удалась....

Comment: Можно верстку посмотреть?

Comment: весь код страницы скинуть?

Comment: Нет, только ссылку на страницу.

Answer (score 0):

1. Если вы ужэ подключили библиотеку jquery почему бы вам не воспользоватся встроенной в jqeury поддержкой ajax
2. overflow-y:hidden; -- это скрывает вертикальный скрол.

Comment: 1. Jqeury только начал изучать, привычка своими силами, но, спасибо, почитаю и исправлю этот недочет.
2. Убрал overflow-y:hidden, теперь текст выходит за пределы модального окна, вот [скрин][1].

[1]: http://s2.ipicture.ru/uploads/20110710/rPAQmU9S.png

Comment: или может предложите другие модальные окна сделанные по умному) а то я в интернете как ни искал, то предлагают подцепить громоские скрипты забивающие память, то его закрыть нельзя, нельзя вставлять таблицы, неработают скрипты в окне, и ширина везде фиксированная а сдесь под размер окна расчитываеться)).. ну вообщем даже не знаю что делать

Comment: Попробуте вместо: overflow-y:hidden; 

записать overflow-y:scroll;